# How to store custom object with CoreData in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a class named `Chord` which subclassed `UILabel` :

```
import UIKit

class Chord: UILabel {

var numTextLine: Int?
var positionInTextLine: CGFloat?
var tempPosInLine: CGFloat?

init(chordName: String, dLine: DLine, xAxis: CGFloat, posInTextLine: CGFloat) {
    // posInLine: CGFloat
    let labelSize = chordName.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)])
    let labelPositionY = ((dLine.upLine.frame.height) - labelSize.height) / 2

    super.init(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: xAxis, y: labelPositionY), size: labelSize))

    self.numTextLine = dLine.numTextLine
    self.positionInTextLine = posInTextLine

    self.tempPosInLine = self.positionInTextLine

    self.text = chordName
    self.font = self.font.fontWithSize(14)
    self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    self.userInteractionEnabled = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

And I would like to persistent store an object called `Song` using CoreData. The `Song` object has an attribute that is an array of `Chord`. So I subclassed `NSManagedObject` as the following :

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Song: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var lyrics: NSString?
    @NSManaged var chords: NSData?
    @NSManaged var title: NSString?
    @NSManaged var artist: NSString?
}
```

And basically I'm stuck there. I have set the attribute's type to `BinaryData` in CoreData model view and tried to use `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(myObject)` before saving the ManagedContext and `NSKeyedArchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(myObject) as? [Chord]` after fetching the entity, but when I unarchive the `NSData` I get an `UILabel` object although I've set `as? [Chord]`.

Anyone can get me on the right way to go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of really important things here:

First, **saving UI objects to Core Data, or any data file, is a terrible idea**. It's technically possible to do what you're trying to do, but it's extremely bad design. You should be saving your data, not your UI objects. You should configure your UI based on your data, not save the actual UI objects. Although MVC is a strategy and not a cast-iron rule, mixing up your model and view to this extent is a really bad idea. What you should do is save all of the relevant data for a chord in your model (details like the name, etc) but not the actual `UILabel` used to display it.

Second, and purely in the interest of understanding Core Data but **not** as something you should do in this specific case-- if you want to save a custom object in Core Data, you'll want to make sure your object's class conforms to `NSCoding`. If you use the "transformable" type for the Core Data attribute, Core Data will use `NSCoding` methods to encode/decode your custom objects. `UILabel` conforms to `NSCoding`, so **if this were a good idea for `UILabel`, which it isn't**, you'd need to override the `NSCoding` method in your subclass.

Comment: Ok I get it, that's actually what I did in the meantime (store only the data used to build the uilabel). I understand now why what I tried to do was a bad idea. Thanks a lot for your answer.